# Connecting two computers

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan, laptop

i have a PC which is connected to a modem router through a Ethernet cable and a laptop which can be connected to the Internet over wireless through the same router. The PC has WinXP SP3 while laptop has Win7. Is there a way to connect this two in some way without using a wireless adapter for the PC or a LAN wire between them?

Comment: Unfortunately I think you have the wrong stack exchange site for this question. Ita not a programming related issue. You need to look into windows networking.

Comment: If they're connected through the same router, then they should *already* be able to see each other. Try pinging one from the other.

Comment: Greg. He called it a modem router. I dont think he knows how to ping.

Comment: Its a modem router or you may say a wireless modem, and i know how to ping

Answer (score 0):

They should be able to talk to each other just fine even though one is connected with a cable and the other is connected wirelessly. For basic stuff, [this guide](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/help/sharing-files-and-printers-with-different-versions-of-windows) may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

im not as well versed on how to fix your situation as i might like to be but depending on how youre trying to connect them (media server or file server or what have you) you could try hosting a file server on one or the other computers and using ftp to send files back and forth. another solution would be to just but a wireless router (unless the purpose of this post was so you didnt have to buy anything) hope ths helps

Comment: He has a wifi router as stated in his question.  Also, if he knew how to share folders on his pcs then a file server would not be nessesary. All he has to do is share a folder and check network neighborhood.

Comment: Thanks Alex, i'll try with file server but working with two different Operating Systems could be tricky...

Comment: Sylar, the mix of winxp and win7 should have no issues with file servers, ftp, or simply enabling a shared folder. Right click in a folder in either operating system, go to properties, and turn on sharing.  Then check network neighborhood.  Nothing tricky